# rspec `described_class` is `nil`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, grpc, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6.0.0.beta3

rspec 3.8.0

I've just installed `rspec-rails` on my Rails app. I ran `rails g rspec:install` and it generated `spec/spec_helper.rb`, `spec/rails_helper.rb` and `.rspec`
The only thing I changed was uncommenting the suggested settings in spec_helper

I'm using [`gruf`](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf) to run a gRPC server, instead of a normal HTTP server.

I've also installed [`gruf-rspec`](https://github.com/bigcommerce/gruf-rspec) intending to use that to test my gruf controllers.

My gruf controller is at `app/rpc/controllers/users_controller.rb` following the gruf documentation. Also the compiled protobuf file is at `app/rpc/users_services_pb.rb`

This is the class signature of the controller:

```
require 'users_services_pb'
require_relative 'permission_helper'

class UsersController < Gruf::Controllers::Base
  bind ::Sil::Rev79::Users::Service
  ...
end
```

My problem is that in my test the `described_class` is `nil`

Here is my test

```
# spec/rpc/users_contollers_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
require 'users_services_pb'

RSpec.describe 'UsersController' do

  describe 'list_users' do
    it 'succeeds' do
      expect(described_class).not_to be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

The test fails.

Why is `described_class` nil and how can I fix this?

Comment: Just an FYI, rails 6 is `6.0.0.rc1` now and using that requires branch `4-0-dev` of rspec-rails which has not been published yet. 

`gem 'rspec-core', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core'`
`gem 'rspec-expectations', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations'`
`gem 'rspec-mocks', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks'`
`gem 'rspec-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails', branch: '4-0-dev'`
`gem 'rspec-support', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks. It shouldn't be a string.

```rb
Rspec.describe UsersController do
 # insert code
end
```